# AWS spot limit increase reasons

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How does amazon intend for spot instances to be used? They seem to be pretty stingy about increasing my limits(from zero). Do I have to be doing something special for a limit increase because I'd like to try out some gaming in the cloud and most of the instances with good gpus use at least 16 virtual-cpus. Is "gaming" a good enough reason for a spot limit increase or is that something they expect me to pay the on-demand rate for?

Comment: Did you limit increase get denied? I've never had an account limit increase get denied. Are you paying for a support plan?

Comment: No, but I'm new to this and when I did make a request they had to escalate it up to a manager or something for approval. They wanted me to write up an explanation on what I plan to use it for and I sort of imagine that "gaming" might not be an acceptable reason.

Comment: I would just tell them the real reason. That process for GPU instances is probably just to make sure you are not trying to mine crypto, which they do not allow on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to try the inf instance type and this is what I wrote and it was approved. And yes, it was escalated but nothing came back other than the approval.

> Limit increase request 1 Service: EC2 Spot Instances Region: US East
> (Northern Virginia) Primary Instance Type: All Inf Spot instances
> Limit name: vCPU Limit New limit value: 50
> ------------ Use case description: When trying to request a inf1.6xlarge spot instance I received this error: ClientError: An
> error occurred (MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded) when calling the
> RequestSpotInstances operation: Max spot instance count exceeded
>
> i'm testing different instance types and would like to be able to
> include inf1 series instances.
>
> As I'm not sure what my limit is now, I want to be sure it is at least
> double what i have.
>
> thank you